# Want to fit cells when title too long under image in table?

Tags: html-table

I want to fit cells when title too long under image in table. When the title of a cell is too long, the cells below do not automatically align the lines evenly.

**https://webvang.net/demo/tlp/tui-pe/** (PRODUCT MODULE IN BOTTOM SITE)

I want to automatically align the lines evenly the same under image:

**https://webvang.net/demo/tlp/images/1.png**

Thank so much!

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.